# SplashScreen.Close() steals focus of MainWindow

Tags: .net, wpf, focus, splash-screen

When the SplashScreen closes (either manually or by AutoClose), it steals the focus of the MainWindow during the fade-out animation. This results in the caption of the main window switching from active to inactive (grey) to active. Is there any trick to keep the SplashScreen from stealing focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Tell the SplashScreen that MainWindow is its parent window. When a child window loses focus, its parent gets the focus. If there is no parent, the window manager decides.</strike>

splashScreen.Show(mainWindow);

**EDIT**:

I just found out that there's a [SplashScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx) class. Looks like you use that class and not just a normal Form as I assumed.

So, I just made a simple WPF app with a SplashScreen and for me the mentioned effect didn't happen. The main window didn't lose focus.

I would suggest you to comment potions of your app's initalization code out until the flashing stops. Then you have a starting point for more research why the focus is lost.

**EDIT2**:

Without knowing your code I tried to reproduce the phenomenon and it wasn't too hard. Whatever I tried, the focus change always happened when the main window was already shown and had focus.

So the best solution I see is to manually show the main window **after** calling the splash screen's Close() method:

1. Remove the StartupUri from App.xaml
2. Show the SplashScreen after starting the app and initializing ressources. After a (currently fixed) delay close the SplashScreen and show the main window:

---

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    const int FADEOUT_DELAY = 2000;

    SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splash.jpg");

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        splash.Show(false, true);

        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (sender, ea) =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                splash.Close(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, FADEOUT_DELAY));
                // you could reduce the delay and show the main window with a nice transition
                Thread.Sleep(FADEOUT_DELAY); 
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MainWindow.Show()));
            };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        MainWindow = new MainWindow();

        // do more initialization
    }
}
```

Comment: The SplashScreen's Show method doesn't accept a Window as parameter. I'm using the build-in SplashScreen object of WPF, it's not a normal window.

Comment: Did you specify a fade-out delay upon close? When the delay is very short it may not be noticable?

Comment: @Joshua: No. Did you try to to remove the fade-out delay? Does it solve your focus problem?

Comment: Yes, when you specify zero delay, the main window does not loose focus. But my question is how to keep focus during the fade-out animation, not how to disable it ;)

Comment: Thanks for all your time and research. I already used the OnStartup event to show the SplashScreen. And .Show has a 'TopMost' flag that is exactly designed to keep the splash-screen on top, while you already show your MainWindow. My loading-code has two stages, and to improve the 'perceived performance' for the user, I already show the mainwindow, while I continue with 'stage two' of the loading process. If I need to wait for FADEOUT_DELAY, my app seems to load slower to the end-user.

Comment: I guess WPF sets the WM_TOPMOST flag for the splash window, and the real solution would be to send the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE flag too, but I can only do that using some nasty P/Invoke calls. So it seems there is no managed-code way to solve this problem, so I will accept your answer. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: @Joshua: setting the delay to a fixed value was just for testing. You should fade out and show the main window when you're finished initializing.

Answer (score 2):

Using ILSpy, I found that the `SplashScreen.Close` method calls `SetActiveWindow` at some point, causing the slpash screen window to become active in the moment it starts closing. (At least in .NET 4.0.) I added a call to my `MainWindow.Focus` just after calling `SplashScreen.Close`, and that resolves the issue.

Otherwise, I could see how the main window was inactive only during the time that the fadeout animation took. Additionally, I show a modal dialog window when the main window has loaded, and this remains active. But when that dialog is closed, the main window wouldn't focus anymore and instead I'll end up in the Visual Studio window or whatever started my application. Inserting the `Focus` call from above also helps in this situation.

BTW, here's a good article that explained me how to use the `SplashScreen` class manually instead of the project file option: http://tech.pro/tutorial/822/wpf-tutorial-using-splash-screens-in-sp1

This is some code from my application:

*In App.xaml.cs:*

```
/// <summary>
/// Application Entry Point.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    splashScreen = new SplashScreen("Splashscreen.png");
    splashScreen.Show(false, true);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);   // For demonstration purposes only!

    App app = new App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

*In my main window ViewModel's Init command (the main window is already completely visible):*

```
private void OnInitCommand()
{
    ConnectDatabase();

    App.SplashScreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    MainWindow.Instance.Focus();   // This corrects the window focus

    SomeDialog dlg = new SomeDialog();
    dlg.Owner = MainWindow.Instance;
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        // Do something with it
    }
    // Now the main window is focused again
}
```